# How do we spell this word in japanese?

Tags: readings, reading-comprehension

I've just began learning Japanese & I saw this word in a web series. I tried to read it but I'm not really sure how to spell it. I'm finding the one left of 王 especially difficult. Can someone help me pls? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: [嬢王](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%AC%A2%20%23kanji)

Answer (score 2):

嬢王{じょうおう}

It’s the name of a manga. (Not to be confused with the normal word 女王{じょおう} “Queen”.)